# CI3 - catch error on insert_batch (unique entry error)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have table with cell that has unique index (**hashCheck**). Is it possible to use **insert_batch**, catch all the entries that are already in db (duplicates), put them in array and insert new records? This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
public function insertSerials($serials, $type)
    {
        $data = [];

        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        foreach ($serials as $serial):
            $data[] = [
                'serial'     => $this->encryption->encrypt($serial),
                'hashCheck'  => hash('xxx', $serial),
                'type'       => $type,
                'date_added' => $now,
            ];
        endforeach;

        try {

            $this->db->insert_batch($this->_table_name, $data);

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            var_dump('<pre>', $e, '</pre>');

        }
    }
```

Comment: Not going to be very useful as none of the CodeIgniter database classes or drivers throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This is only way I can think of to accomplish your goal. Maybe not so elegant but it should work.

```
  public function insertSerials($serials, $type)
  {
    $data = [];
    $pre_existing = [];

    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    foreach($serials as $serial)
    {
      $data[] = [
        'serial' => $this->encryption->encrypt($serial),
        'hashCheck' => hash('xxx', $serial),
        'type' => $type,
        'date_added' => $now,
      ];

      //test for existing hashCheck
      $query = $this->db->get_where($this->_table_name,
                                    array('hashCheck' => $data['hashCheck']));
      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
      {
        $pre_existing[] = $data;
      }
      else
      {
        $this->db->insert($this->_table_name, $data);
      }
    }
  }
```

I would feel bad about putting `db->insert()` in a loop except that is what `insert_batch()` eventually does.